# Promise { <pending> } on node js async function using map

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

Trying to inject data of an async function into another and returning it together, but keep receiving:
`[ Promise { < pending > }, Promise { < pending > } ]`.

Resuming, I have an array X, got from an async func, which I iterate and for every item on array X, I call another async func that give me array Z related with the item on array X. Using the map function, I want to join Array Z with the item related on array X

Code:

```js
 public async execute(): Promise<any> {
    let resultModules;

    this.entityRepository.findAll().then(res => {
      resultModules = res.map(async seg => {
        const modules = await this.segmentModuleRepository.findBySegmentFormatted(
          seg.id,
        );

        console.log('modules: ', modules);

        return {
          ...seg,
          modules,
        };
      });
      console.log('resultModules', resultModules);
    });

    return resultModules;
  }
```

Console:

[image: console image]

`resultModules` should have all the array X items plus array Z for each of them related.

Comment: Please post code, not images of code ... This way others can help you fixing your code without having to retype everything on their own (which hardly anybody would do ...)

Comment: [I downvoted because an image of your code is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to await the promises in the array resulting from `map` using `Promise.all`

```
public async execute(): Promise<any> {
  return this.entityRepository.findAll()
    .then(res => Promise.all(res.map(async seg => {
        const modules = await this.segmentModuleRepository.findBySegmentFormatted(seg.id);
        console.log('modules: ', modules);
        return
        {
          ...seg,
          modules,
        };
      }
      ))
    )
}
```